# removing the last blank line from txt file using java

Tags: java, file

First I am writing to a file and I need to read that file again but what I identify is that the file that is being written has a blank line at the end which causes problem. Although I am using replaceAll("\s","") command to avoid any spaces in string when writing to a file but it again creates space or blank lines at the end so how can I remove that to make sure that the file ends where the string end rather than having spaces at the end of the file.
Here is chuck it is a bit lengthy but if it is required i'll post that too

```
str2= str2+","+str;
str2= str2.replaceAll("\\s","");
str2.replaceAll("(?m)^[ \t]*\r?\n", "");
File testFile1 = new File("G:/softwares/xampp/htdocs/Simulator/testFile1.csv");
File parent = testFile1.getParentFile();
if(!parent.exists() && !parent.mkdirs())
{
    throw new IllegalStateException("Couldn't create dir: " + parent);
}
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(testFile1,false);        
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
pw.println(str2);
pw.flush();
pw.close();
```

Comment: Either you have added that blank line, but it is difficult to judge without seeing your code, or the editor you use automatically inserts a blank line at the end.

Comment: str2 & str1 are strings which are concatenated in a loop first and then the above code follows and this testfile has to be read later for further use but due to blank line at the end it doesn't give correct output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `str2.replaceAll()` may be replacing a line at the end and leaving the line blank.

Use `str2.trim()` or move `str2 = str2.replaceAll("\\s","")` after the second `replaceAll()`.

This will probably not fix the problem since PrintWriter adds a `\n` after every line. Try using an `OutputStream`.

Replace:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(testFile1,false);        
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
pw.println(str2);
pw.flush();
pw.close();
```

with:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(testFile1);
out.write(str2.trim().getBytes());
out.close();
```

Comment: moving str2 = str2.replaceAll("\\s","") after the second replaceAll() because I added second replaceAll() later when looking at the output so had been testing it with first replaceAll() only but let me try this trim() function.

Comment: @Matia, you need to use `str2 = str2.trim();`, since a String object is immutable.

Comment: No it still doesn't help it still has a space at the end even using trim().

Comment: Try using an OutputStream to write bytes to it.

Comment: I am not familiar to that How do we do that? I mean I do have an idea about i/o stream but is it function you are talking about or what?

Comment: Do I need to make separate class for this since I am getting and on first line when I replace it. The error is "OutputStream is abstract; cannot be instantiated" though I am already importing java.io.OutputStream;

Comment: @Maria: Oops, use `FileOutputStream`

Comment: Yes it works :)....Thank a lot really grateful for your help and time :)....One last thing hopefully this will overwrite to my same file rather than appending it when it is invoked again and again.

Comment: Yes, it will overwrite unless you open it in append mode.

Comment: Also, if this answered helped, you can click the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: it's not working in my case

Answer (score 1):

You might `trim()` your String when writing (or when reading):

```
str2.trim();
```

For experience I must said that when you write in a file, generally a white space is added (It happened to me in an assembly program). So if you read any file again, you may `trim()` the content String, as another solution.

Comment: I had been using replaceAll() everywhere assuming it would not create any space in a file but let me try this too

Comment: No it still doesn't help it still has a space at the end even using trim().